# How can I tell Visual Studio to rearrange my comments onto multiple lines?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts

Sometimes when I'm commenting my code in Visual Studio I find that my comments drag out past the rest of my code. Are there any shortcuts, methods, or extensions that rearrange these one-liner-monstrosities into nicely formatted comments spread across multiple lines? Formatting the document does not appear to affect comments.

Say, for example, I wrote a long comment like this:

```
// If at this point the task has not completed it has exceeded the maximum time and a timeout exception should be thrown.
```

What would be an easy way to rearrange it into something like the following (other than by hand)?

```
// If at this point the task has not completed it has exceeded the maximum
// time and a timeout exception should be thrown.
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  One thing to think about is that comments in your code is often considered a code smell (a bad idea).  You should really be refactoring you code into smaller methods and naming the methods appropriately to show your intent.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. I hadn't really thought of it that way. +1

Comment: I would recommend reading a book by Robert C Martin called "Clean Code" it will change the way you think about coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CodeMaid](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496) extension includes [Comment Formatting](http://www.codemaid.net/documentation/#formatting) to wrap at a specified column.

Comment: That extension looks sweet. Thanks Sergey!